# What makes Domain-Driven Design worthwhile?

Tags: domain-driven-design, agile

We are trying to apply Domain-Driven Design in our project. However, the modeling efforts are huge and somehow the modeling seems to conflict with agile principles as a lot of upfront design is done. On the other hand the actual benefit are diffuse or are rather longterm whereas the "requirements analysis / modeling overhead" felt is an acute and ongoing problem.

So, the question comes up: What makes Domain-Driven Design worthwhile?
What are the short-term benefits?

Aside from your experience (which I find very interesting though): Is there an undisputable, logical answer?

Answer (score 14):

### DDD - Continous Refactoring

I guess I'd clarify that Domain Driven Design doesn't call for a tonne of up front modelling - what it calls for is conversations with domain experts, knowledge crunching to gain an intuitive understanding of the domain through 'sensible sounding' use of the ubiquitous language, and continuous refinement of all of the above.

The value of the tactical patterns (aggregates, etc.) is not  around getting the model perfect up front, but from structuring your application such that when you inevitably realize that there is a better way of expressing the domain in a model, you can iterate and incorporate your insights into the updated model.

So - in that sense, it is highly supportive of an agile approach.

The best reference for this is the source - "Part III Refactoring Toward Deeper Insight" of the [Blue Book' by Eric Evans](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215)

I'd recommend not trying to 'waterfall' your model and then 'agile' your code - 'agile' both of them, and accept that you will be refactoring your code not just when you find a more elegant way of solving technical problems, but also when you find a more elegant way of modelling business problems.

### Undisputable Logical Answer?

In terms of an "undisputable logical answer" - to be honest I'm not sure you'll find one.  DDD is an approach that is applied differently by different people - it is not an algorithm that can be analysed for it's Big O complexity.

My experience is that programs with anemic models and business logic scattered through a collection of loosely related services struggle to iterate and incorporate deeper insights into the business requirements because changes to the rules can have unforeseeable repercussions throughout the system.  They encourage systems where new requirements are satisfied by stuffing behavior into places it was never intended to go, and you end up having conversations that involve multiple layers of remembering that code using the word 'employee' kind of sometimes relates to requirements for 'students' and 'teachers'.

Concentrating the essence of each entity into a class, and exposing it's behavior behind intention revealing interfaces enables effective reasoning about the impact of changes, thus enabling continuous refactoring of the model - both as understanding grows and requirements change.

### Edit - How to Pursuade Others

From your comment, I now understand your intent better - I misinterpreted the question that you were looking to be persuaded that DDD is worthwhile - rather you are looking for an argument to present to your team to persuade them that it is worthwhile!

Unfortunately that is more of a inter-personal question than a technical one, as people are often not persuaded by arguments once they are convinced they are on the right path.

Perhaps if you have time you could produce a proof of concept of some acceptance tests and domain models to illustrate the method using real concepts from your domain?  You can then show how easily the tests and models can be evolved as understanding grows, and ideally demonstrate an insight gained by actively modeling the domain in code and exercising the model.  This is key, I believe, as in my opinion, such insights can only be gained by actively *doing*, and will *never* be arrived at through meeting room navel gazing.

Comment: I'd also suggest that if the upfront modelling effort is proving cumbersome - revisit the strategic patterns and the breakdown into bounded contexts.  It should be possible to break most systems down into bounded contexts of < 10 models - again, further simplifying the analysis of the requirements for that context.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I totally agree that DDD doesn't require upfront modeling in terms of an exact specification. I know DDD goes well with agile. However, my team is focusing on the technical stuff the developers are producing very quickly and not talking about the domain. So, it's techno-driven design right now. The general feeling is "we do not have time to do all the conversations and knowledge crunching" that is required (at least from my perspective). So, I would like to say: "look, if you do DDD, the task you are currently working on will become much easier" or something equally supportive.

Comment: Edited to add some advice on persuading others.

Answer (score 2):

Are you creating executable models or paper? If you create (acceptance test-driven) executable models like in [exploratory modeling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qlQx25QCRIk), the overhead is practically zero

Comment: Thanks Stephan. Exploratory modeling sounds perfect. Currently, there are executable wireframes and context scenarios. I'm trying to establish exemplary acceptance tests as I experienced in others projects that they are a good basis for domain modeling and other things, too. However, the domain experts are reluctant to write binding tests as they are afraid of missing important things. They would like to discuss things more on their side - and this feels a lot like "upfront designing". Not sure how to convince them to jump in at the deep end and to write those tests etc. What's in it for them?

Comment: Perhaps it helps to tell them that the goal of the binding tests is not to be complete, but to constrain the solution. Adding more tests gets one closer and closer to the solution. The tricky part is to over- and under-constrain as little as possible